"Solver Only Outputs '1' in All Cells – What Am I Doing Wrong?"
trying to use solver for the first time, not sure if its the best tool for this problem.
example of dummy table
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1miNjJNFaG3DWJVDNYgenrTbw4rH07gmBaLJv7mkzI_M/edit?usp=sharing
what i am trying to do is adding a next column with solver header, where it would assign 1,2,3
in the j1 have the sum of m1,m2,m3.
k1 = 6878, k2 = 13843.42, k3= 1000 then in m1 have this function =SUMIF(H2:H82, 1, B2:B82), m2 =SUMIF(H2:H82, 2, B2:B82), m3 = =SUMIF(H2:H82, 3, B2:B82)
and my solver setup looks like
enter image description here
when i press solve everywhere puts 1, what i am doing wrong.
Can it be done with solver or do i need to try to create a VBA macro?
Thanks for help.
have a nice day
tryed solve everywhere puts 1, what i am doing wrong.


The SUMIF() formula in your file is not quite correct; the third and first arguments should be swapped.

Solver can find an alternative solution with the following configuration.



